# Why do I need to use a callback is this case

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I'm trying to work out the Coinbase Pro node.js API.

When running this:

```
const buyParams = {
  price: '100.00', // USD
  size: '1', // BTC
  product_id: 'BTC-USD',
};
authedClient.buy(buyParams, callback);
```

I have the following error `callback is not defined`

So I'm trying to understand how does callback work exactly.

What is the callback here exactly? If I understand well I need to define the callback which is a function but what would be the purpose of this function? I this because I need to wait for the answer from `authedClient` method? Or this something else?

Comment: Are you asking what a callback is? Or are you asking why you need to define it?

Comment: I'm asking why do I need to define it.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation for the API?

Comment: I'm clearly in the situation where "I don't know what I don't know" so I don't know if I need to assume that there is stuff I should now and if there is some information I should find in the doc. Based on seeIts answer it is clearer to me.

Comment: There is no built-in function called `callback`, meaning right now you're just trying to pass in some undefined variable.

Comment: You need to define it, because you can't reference an undefined variable.

Comment: so here I need to build a callback function to handle the response of `.buy`... and I guess I need to write this variable according to the documentation, right?

Comment: I don't know why you're asking us. We'd only have to look up what you'd have to do in the documentation. Do you think the documentation is misleading you somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.buy` method will call provided callback when it finishes.
You probably want to do something depending on the result.
That's why you need that callback.

Comment: Ok so I need a callback here because of the way the `.buy` the method is defined? So I need to check the documentation to understand the behavior of the `.buy` method so I can build my call back right?

Comment: Correct! It is always a good idea to check documentation of the libraries/methods you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Usually callbacks are used when a task takes some time and for one of two reasons: to "give" you the value that took so long to prodce, or to notify you about an event, usually "I'm done".

In NodeJs it's a common pattern to use callbacks like this `function(error, value){...}` where the function is either called with an error, if one occurred `callback(err);` or the value `callback(null, result);`

In your case, you need to read in the API-Doc how and when the callback is called. What arguments are provided, etc.

> I'm asking why do I need to define it.

Because the author of the `buy()` method thaught that every user of this function would want to be noified when this task is done, and would want to recieve whatever value this callback provides, so there must be an error, if you don't provide a proper callback-function. That's why he throws an Error.

Answer (score 0):

You should read API carefully, but in this situation the second parameter of **.buy** is a function you passed to it to execute after .buy runs.

```
const buyParams = {
price: '100.00', // USD
size: '1', // BTC
product_id: 'BTC-USD',
};
const cb = ()=> {
 console.log('Buy finished!');
}
authedClient.buy(buyParams, cb);
```

you should read API document for parameters of cb. but in simple way it's some thing like up code! and after buy finished cb called and log the 'Buy Finished';

feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you use callback functions in order to be called when the functions finish his work. But why callbacks and not simply catch the return result of the function? Because of synchronous events.

Check out [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) and the following code to understand better the problem of async functions and why javascript programmers solve it by using callback functions

```js
function syncFunc() {
   return "finished!";
}

function asyncFunc() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return "finished!";
  },1);
}

function asyncFuncWithCallback(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback("finished");
  },1);
}

console.log(`syncFunc: ${syncFunc()}`);
console.log(`asyncFunc: ${asyncFunc()}`);
asyncFuncWithCallback((value) => {
     console.log(`asyncFuncWithCallback: ${value}`);
});
```